# Is query_id unique among all the Snowflake accounts?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is query_id unique among all the Snowflake accounts?

You can see query_id is a UUID string in the picture below. So I am wondering if the Snowflake generated query_id is unique across all the Snowflake accounts. And if Snowflake users can submit query_id to Snowflake support for help. And if Snowflake support can distinguish the account and the QUERY details by query_id.

[image]

Comment: The query id is unique at the account level. I think the support person will need your account name. But based on my experience, snowflake support cannot see your data, they can suggest query tuning opportunities which does not required data to investigate

Comment: @RajibDeb Do you think `query id` is unique across all the accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Support can infer a lot of information from the Query ID and can look up additional information on that specific query (all related to metadata), but they may ask you to confirm other pieces.

For example, account confirmation so that they know you are an authorized user of the account and aren't someone random who copied a Query ID from Stack Overflow.  If you are enabled for Snowflake Support and can submit a case (see link), then you are already confirmed an authorized user for the account. https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: Do you think query id is unique across all the accounts? @Suzy Lockwood

Comment: I don't think there's any documented guarantee, but for what purpose are you needing a confirmation?  As I mentioned, if someone is submitting a case to Support, they need more than a Query ID to be an authorized user of the account.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the Query ID appears to be a UUID, but there's no documented guarantee that a Query ID is unique beyond the guarantee that the UUID standard itself provides (read: it's extraordinarily unlikely, *but not impossible*, that two UUIDs will collide). So for whatever purpose you need it, Query ID is likely to suffice as unique.

It's not, however, a documented guarantee that Snowflake will continue to use UUIDs for query ids indefinitely. If tomorrow the engineering team decides to use some other constructed string, they probably can. I don't know why they would though.

Answer (score 0):

QueryID is based on UUID and they are unique among all the snowflake accounts. So when you are submitting a case and you just provide queryID and nothing else even in those cases, Snowflake support will be able to locate your query. Though Support may obviously ask for more information in order to help you better.